# How can I improve this output to not include so much html?

Tags: php

I am fairly new to php and was wondering how I would go about improving this code. I know its not perfect but any constructive criticism is encouraged as I am trying to better myself in PHP. Please all I ask is that if you do answer with a way to improve it you expand upon the answer a little and let me know why it is better so I can get the full over view of the improvement.

```
public function displayArticle(){
    //Check to see if we are getting the home page
    if($_GET['page'] == 'home'){
        //Display the results formatted
        $content = "<article class=\"igpPost\">";
            $content .= "<div class=\"igpPost-Divider\"></div>";
            $content .= "<header>";
            $content .= "<h3><a href=\"#\">Ready Up – StarCraft 2, LoL, and Dota 2 pros head to DreamHack Summer</a></h3>";
            $content .= "<div class=\"igpPost-AuthTime\"><span>Posted By: </span><a href=\"#\">Cameron Lockhart</a> <span>at 07:44PM on June 15, 2012</span></div>";
            $content .= "<div class=\"igpPost-AuthTime\"><span>Tags: </span><a href=\"#\">TAG HERE</a> ,<a href=\"#\">TAG HERE</a> ,<a href=\"#\">TAG HERE</a> ,<a href=\"#\">TAG HERE</a> ,<a href=\"#\">TAG HERE</a> ,<a href=\"#\">TAG HERE</a></div>";
            $content .= "<div class=\"igpPost-Img\"><img src=\"images/news/DreamHack-Summer-2012-logo.jpg\"/></div>";
            $content .= "</header>";
            $content .= "<p>Did last week’s MLG Spring Championship leave you thirsting for more eSports? Then DreamHack Summer 2012 has you covered. With well-attended tournaments for StarCraft 2, League of Legends, and Dota 2, DreamHack should keep you busy throughout the weekend and into the work-week. It starts tomorrow at 11 AM Eastern, and continues through Monday, with the StarCraft 2 Grand Final scheduled for 5:15 PM Eastern.</p>";
            $content .= "<footer class=\"igpPost-Footer\">";
            $content .= "<div class=\"igpPost-ReadMore\">";
            $content .= "<h1><a href=\"#\">Read More..</a></h1>";
            $content .= " </div>";
            $content .= "</footer>";
            $content .= "</article>";
    }
        //If it is not the home page and it is a single article
        if($_GET['article']){
            //Display the article formatted
        }
}
```

Also this is obviously not a completed script but looking at it it looks like to much for PHP. I read some tutorials and I think they sent me in the wrong direction with being correct and using good PHP.

Update: I went through and tried to revise some of the code so that it gave a more descriptive overview:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles LIMIT $number";
        $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            //Display the results formatted
            $content = "<article class=\"igpPost\">";
            $content .= "<div class=\"igpPost-Divider\"></div>";
            $content .= "<header>";
            $content .= "<h3><a href=\"index.php?article=" . $row['id'] ."\">" . $row['title'] . "</h3>";
            $content .= "<div class=\"igpPost-AuthTime\"><span>Posted By: </span><a href=\"#\">" . $row['author'] . "</a> <span>at " . formatDateTime($row['datetime']) . "</span></div>";
            $content .= "<div class=\"igpPost-AuthTime\"><span>Tags: </span>";
            $content .= "<div class=\"igpPost-Img\"><img src=\"" . $row['imglocation'] ."\"/></div>";
            $content .= "</header>";
            $content .= "<p>" . $row['content'] . "</p>";
            $content .= "<footer class=\"igpPost-Footer\">";
            $content .= "<div class=\"igpPost-ReadMore\">";
            $content .= "<h1><a href=\"index.php?article=" . $row['id'] ."\">Read More..</a></h1>";
            $content .= " </div>";
            $content .= "</footer>";
            $content .= "</article>";

            echo $content;
        }
```

This is what im going for, im basically trying to separate the html from the PHP but insert the dynamic content in the places it needs to be. This is all within a class.

Comment: Is the content always static?

Comment: while it's not bad to use `$_GET` within a class function, I suggest passing it as a parameter from outside e.g. `displayArticle($type)` and within and the function do a `switch ($type)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variety of things here, including heredoc syntax (the direct equivalent of what you have):

```
            $content = <<<END
<article class="igpPost">
    <!-- ... -->
</article>
END;
```

(Note that you can't indent the `END;` part.)

Another option is to use output buffering and `include` a content script:

```
ob_start();
include 'someViewFile.php';
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just exit out of PHP when you can, unless you need to do something additional with the `$content` variable. I'm not sure when/where/how your calling your function but I'm assuming after some checks and what not

```
<?php 
  //Do any checks/validation etc here before you send something out to the server

?>
<html><head><!--HEADER STUFF HERE--></head>
<body>
<!-- anything you want before your content here -->

<?php
if($_GET['page'] == 'home'){
?>
<div class="igpPost-Divider"></div>
<header>
 ....
</footer>
</article>
<?php
}
  //If it is not the home page and it is a single article
    if($_GET['article']){ ?>
       <!-- HTML for article here --> 
    <?php
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like spaghetti code, overtime this will make everything hard to look at.

Comment: I haven't really done any serious work with PHP and in a larger scope this style probably gets unmanageable. But this way of doing things is one of the things I love about PHP you can just break in and out of HTML even inside control structures like if and for

Comment: I'd have a few things to say if they guys at work wrote code like this. It's perfect for beginners, but not an approach to be encouraged. It's hell to debug, indentation is a nightmare and impossible to generally read. Not marking down (as you took time for a great example, and it could be considered right for a beginner) but it's really not the right way to teach someone to move forward. Sorry for the frankness.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about cutting down on the HTML since I'm not aware of your specific needs, however, you can greatly simplify the PHP code with a HEREDOC.

HEREDOC ([PHP Manual HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)) is a method for outputting strings and outputting variables within as with double-quotes. The difference is that there is no need to escape any quotes within.

Your code can use a HEREDOC like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles LIMIT $number";
    $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        //Display the results formatted
        $dateTime = formatDateTime($row['datetime']) // functions cannot be used in HEREDOCS, so I replace it with the variable $dateTime declared here
        $content = <<<HERE
<article class="igpPost">
<div class="igpPost-Divider"></div>
<header>
    <h3><a href="index.php?article="$row['id']">$row['title']</h3>
    <div class="igpPost-AuthTime"><span>Posted By: </span><a href="#">$row['author']</a> <span>at $dateTime</span></div>
    <div class="igpPost-AuthTime"><span>Tags: </span>
    <div class="igpPost-Img"><img src="$row['imglocation']"/></div>
    </header>
    <p>$row['content']</p>
    <footer class="igpPost-Footer">
    <div class="igpPost-ReadMore">
    <h1><a href="index.php?article="$row['id']">Read More..</a></h1></div>
    </footer>
</article>
HERE;
echo $content;
}
```

Comment: The line "<div class="igpPost-AuthTime"><span>Posted By: </span><a href="#">$row['author']</a> <span>at $dateTime</span></div>" may be an issue. I think the # in <a href="#"> will look like a comment to php. So you'll need a workaround there.

Comment: yea that was just a place holder for the html rough draft. I definitely will go ahead and use heredoc I really appreciate the help and explanations.